# Turn off prompt for ReSharper Annotations

Tags: c#, resharper

When I have ReSharper auto-generate interface stubs, for example, INotifyPropertyChanged, it brings up a popup stating that it cannot find ReSharper annotations, and asks me if I want to include them. I never do.

[image]

How do I disable this prompt? I have tried unchecking Code Inspection > Automatically propagate annotations, and Code Editing > Context Actions > Implement INotifyPropertyChanged pattern. Neither appears to have any effect on the auto implementation. If there's a setting that is more explicit, I've managed to miss it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, there is no way to disable such prompt, it is not handled by `Automatically propagate annotations` checkbox. Such checkbox has been introduced for another reason. However, it makes sense to cover this case as well. [Feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-466756) which you might follow.